# Getting null in javascript from a ASP TAG

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using a Web form with Master Page im getting null from a javascript sentence:

Javascript:

```
//becouse I was getting error with this line I change the trigger to the onclick attribute on the button tag, but keep getting the same error
//document.getElementById("btn_fecha").onclick = function() {validaFecha()};
function validaFecha(){
var in_dia = document.getElementById("<%=drp_dia.ClientID%>");
var in_mes = document.getElementById("<%=drp_mes.ClientID%>");
var in_agno = document.getElementById("<%=drp_agno.ClientID%>");

var dia = in_dia.options[in_dia.selectedIndex].value;
var mes = in_mes.options[in_mes.selectedIndex].value;
var agno = in_agno.options[in_agno.selectedIndex].value;

var dia_f = (dia < 10) ? "0" + dia : "" + dia;
var mes_f = (mes < 10) ? "0" + mes : "" + mes;

var fecha = new Date(agno + "-" + mes_f + "-" + dia_f)
var fecha_f = formatDate(fecha);

document.getElementById("txt_fecha_nacimiento").value = fecha_f;
}

function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

and this are the tags Im having problem to get:

```
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drp_dia" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drp_mes" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</td
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drp_agno" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
<button Class="btn btn-secondary" ID="btn_fecha" type="button" onclick="validaFecha()">GUARDAR</button>
</td>
```

This is the error Im getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1LjV.png)

Comment: It would help to see the rendered HTML since your javascript is reporting a NULL for one of your elements...

Comment: something you render on `ID="drp_dia"` dropDownlist and the selected index is not exist, or its out of the options

Answer (score 0):

I changed all the " in my Javascript to simple ' and put ClientIDMode="static" in all my asp tags (the ones I wanted to get), and only use the id in the javascript get by element not the "<%=ID.ClientID%>":

```
function validaFecha(){
var in_dia = document.getElementById('drp_dia');
var in_mes = document.getElementById('drp_mes');
var in_agno = document.getElementById('drp_agno');

var dia = in_dia.options[in_dia.selectedIndex].value;
var mes = in_mes.options[in_mes.selectedIndex].value;
var agno = in_agno.options[in_agno.selectedIndex].value;

var dia_f = (dia < 10) ? "0" + dia : "" + dia;
var mes_f = (mes < 10) ? "0" + mes : "" + mes;

var fecha = new Date(agno + "-" + mes_f + "-" + dia_f)
var fecha_f = formatDate(fecha);

document.getElementById("txt_fecha_nacimiento").value = fecha_f;
}

function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

it started to work